# Creating A simple Add Calculator

Tags: qt, qlineedit

```
void FindCrap::on_BtnAdd_clicked()
{
QString fnum = ui->TxtFnum->text();
QString snum = ui->TxtSnum->text();
ui->TxtAns->setText(QString(fnum.toInt() + snum.toInt()));
}
```

nothing is happening when i run this code .. not even an error . the BtnAdd doesnt work what seems to be the problem ..

Answer (score 2):

First of all be sure that your slot is called correctly. Use a `qDebug()<<"something";` at the first of the slot and see whether something will be displayed in `output window` or not. Or simply set a breakpoint at first of the slot and debug it.
Second, change the last line :

```
ui->TxtAns->setText(QString(fnum.toInt() + snum.toInt()));
```

to

```
ui->TxtAns->setText(QString::number(fnum.toInt() + snum.toInt()));
```

I mean use `QString::number` function to convert a number to QString